# Accessing FB Graph API using Ruby 1.8 and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, ruby-1.8

I'm adding Facebook functionality on to a site running Ruby 1.8.6 and rails 1.2.3.

Are there any gems that will let me use facebook's graph api with these versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Koala - https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki Really a solid gem. Wait, Rails 1.2.3? Did I read it right?

Comment: Unfortunately. It's a professor at my school's baby. Anyway, we decided on a different route. thanks anyways.